# What do the 可 mean in 可现在想起来可真是记忆犹新呀 and 我可要出点丑了?

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence:

> 同学们，我的新家安电话的时侯还是几年前，可现在想起来可真是记忆犹新呀！不信？那我就讲给你听听，我可要出点丑了！

Could you please explain?

1 可现在想起来可真是记忆犹新呀！why is there a second 可 here?

2。我可要出点丑了！what is the meaning of 可 here and what does 出点丑 mean?

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

可现在想起来可真是记忆犹新呀！

The first 可 is the abbreviated form of 可是, meaning "however":

*The phone was intalled a few years ago, **however**, I still remember it as clearly as if it's yesterday.*

The second 可 is used to emphasize 真是. This 可 can be omitted.

我可要出点丑了！

Here 可要 is used to draw more attention from, or to give heads-ups, warnings, or threats to the listeners. 可要 can be reduced to 要.

出丑 means to reveal something shameful or private about oneself to others. 出点丑 simply reduces the amount/intensity of the 'shame' being revealed.

Comment: 出点丑 is, in my view, better translated as -- "some embarrassment" "Shameful" is too strong a word here and whatever 丑 there is need not necessarily be private. One could 出点丑 even when making a formal speech in an unfamiliar language or singing a song out of tune. Nothing shameful here. So, 出点丑  is a kind of preemptive apology, (formal or informal), designed to deter or prevent an anticipated embarrassing situation or occurrence.